# Как ускорить циклы?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть простая задача[image: Пример от 1 до 5]

суть заключается в том, что мальчик любит рисовать и надо помочь ему посчитать количество клеток которые он закрасит в зависимости от количества Елок.
Вводные данные N
Выходные данные площадь закрашенной поверхности
Я сделал простоt решение на питоне:

```
N = 10000
b = 0
a = 0
for i in range(1, N+1):
    a += i*2+1
    for g in range(1, i+1):
        b += g*2
print(a+b)
```

но дело в том, что когда слшком большие числа такой код выполняется очень долго, как я могу его ускорить используя именно питон? Заранее благодарю за проявленный интерес.Желательно встроенными библиотеками, если они понадобятся.

Comment: Подумать над тем, можно ли данную реккурентную формулу превратить в обычную.

Comment: Это при каких же `N` долго выполняется - порядка 10 000? А, ну да, я что-то слепой )) Я бы тупо в `numba.njit` обернул, если думать лениво.

Comment: это арифметическая прогрессия, решается одной формулой

Comment: Что такое numba.njut и что такое реккурентная формула? да именно после 10000 делается долго, но суть и была в том что ограничение по времени 1секунда. Типо олимпиадное задание. Я новичсок в программировании. Потому буду не против любой инфаормации @CrazyElf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Взглянем на картинку под другим углом зрения...
Возьмём для примера ёлку для числа 3:

[image: ёлка]

- Слева (красным) у нас получается арифметическая прогрессия 1,2,3. Её сумма будет: `(1+n)/2*n`.
- Правая часть (жёлтая) - то же самое. Так что умножаем на 2: `(1+n)/2*n * 2`. Деление и умножение на 2 сокращаем: `(1+n)*n`.
- Ствол (зелёный) - ни что иное как `n*2 + 1`. Прибавляем к предыдущему: `(1+n)*n + n*2 + 1`. `2n` заносим под скобку, и...

Конечная формула площади одной ёлки: `(3+n)*n + 1`.

---

Теперь составим ещё одну последовательность, уже из этих формул:

```
(3 + 1)*1 + 1
(3 + 2)*2 + 1
(3 + 3)*3 + 1
(3 + 4)*4 + 1
...
(3 + n)*n + 1
```

Или если раскрыть скобки:

```
3*1 + 1*1 + 1
3*2 + 2*2 + 1
3*3 + 3*3 + 1
3*4 + 4*4 + 1
...
3*n + n*n + 1
```

Итого:

- первый столбец: нужно посчитать сумму арифметической прогрессии `3*(1+2+3+...+n)` = `3*(1+n)/2*n`
- второй столбец: сумму квадратов `1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + ... + n^2` = `n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6`
- ну и в третьем столбце сумма равна `n`

```
3*(1+2+3+...+n) + (1^2+2^2+3^2+...+n^2) + n = 3*(1+n)/2*n + n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6 + n
```

Дальше выносим деление за скобки, группируем, раскрываем скобки:

```
(3*(1+n)/2*n*6 + n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6*6 + n*6)/6
(9*(1+n)*n + n*(n+1)*(2*n+1) + n*6)/6
((2*n+10)*(1+n)*n + n*6)/6
((2*n+10)*(n+n*n) + n*6)/6
(2*n*n + 10*n + 2*n*n*n + 10*n*n + n*6)/6
(2*(n**3) + 12*(n**2) + 16*n)/6
```

И получаем конечную формулу для суммы площадей всех ёлок.

```
((n**3) + 6*(n**2) + 8*n)/3
```

> *Упс. Забыл, что для решения задачи зачем-то должны быть использованы умения программирования на Питон. Ну да ладно... :)*

Comment: шикарный ответ!!!

Comment: Благодарю, просто шикарный ответ. Это типо олимпиадное задание было и суть в том, что я не получил 20 баллов потому что с сильно большими числами программа выполнялась больше 1 секунды. Благодарю вас за столь подробное объяснение.

Comment: @Kynomi Имея формулу, время вычисления становится константным О(1) и от n в принципе не зависящем. При программировании очень не лишен навык поиска оптимального алгоритма. Иногда в результате поиска, как в данном случае, и на программирование ничего не остаётся, собственно. :)

Answer (score 8):

По моему, здача не очень сложнА.

Смотрите.

Каждая следкющая ёлка образуется пририсовыванием к предыдущей "буквы Т" с "палочкой" размером 2N+1 и одной дополнительной клеткой внизу - "ножкой".

То есть,площадь следующей ёлки S(n) = S(n-1) + 2n+2.

```
| n | S(n) | SumS(n) |
----------------------
| 0 | 1    |         |
| 1 | 5    | 5       |
| 2 | 11   | 16      |
| 3 | 19   | 35      |
| 4 | 29   | 64      |
```

Вообще, выскажу смелое предположение, что `S(n) = (n+1)**2 + n`. Я не проверял, но похоже на правду.

А теперь мы всё можем посчитать за один цикл: в одной переменной считать площать очередной ёлки, в другой - накапливать сумму всех площадей.

Код нужен?

Вот он:

```
    N = 10000
    SumS = 0
    S = 1
    for i in range(1, N+1):
        S += 2*i+2
        SumS += S
    print(SumS)
```

Только проверьте, я всё таки из головы писал, без пайтона под рукой

> Я вообще не понимаю как ваша формула работает. Что значит S(n-1)

S(n) - площадь n-той ёлки

в коде SumS - общая площадь всех ёлок.

А формула получается, если заметить следующую закономерность, нарисованную на картинке (грубо говоря, дорисовыванием чего следующая ёлка получается из предыдущей):

[image: Следующая ёлка из предыдущей]

Comment: Буду благодарен примеру кода, ибо пока что я не очень понял суть работы, сейачс вчитаюсь и попробую понять. Мышление реально хорошо, я новичок, рад любому опыту, и любым подсказкам. Спасибо вам

Comment: не нужен цикл, для суммы членов прогрессии есть простая формула

Comment: @Эникейщик - согласен, просто так как есть цикл - было лень формулу выводить, просто было посчитать в цикле

Comment: да зачем ее выводить, она известна и есть почти везде, например, в первых строках википедии

Comment: @Эникейщик что за формула такая, я видимо слишком неправильно мыслю, но такую формулу я найти не могу, хотел бы ее узнать, ибо именно избавление от цикла и помогло бы мне избавиться от проблем с временем. Если вы еще и обхясните эту формулу я буду вам благодарен. Рад что есть такие отзывчивые люди.

Comment: Я же написал - формула суммы членов арифметической прогрессии. Гуглится в два нажатия.

Comment: А, сорян. Это прогрессия второго порядка. Тут действительно чуток посложнее.

Comment: @S.H. Я вообще не понимаю как ваша формула работает. Что значит S(n-1)
S это скопившаяся площадь или что? А n я так понимаю номер елки.

Comment: @S.H. на какой формуле это основано, я хоть ее загуглю посмотрю что к чему

Comment: Только я вижу тут обыкновенную арифметическую прогрессию? И элементарную формулу исходя из этого `(3 + n)*n + 1`.

Comment: @GrAnd - круто! формулу для т-го члена я в ответ вписал, а еще один шаг сделать не догадался!

Comment: Ради прикола расписал как посчитать сумму площадей вообще не используя циклы. У меня для суммы всех площадей вышла такая формула - `((n**3) + 6*(n**2) + 8*n)/3`.

Comment: да, я уже увидел. вот что значит разобрать задачу по косточкам!

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 10000
d = 5
sa = 5
for i in range(2, n+1):
    d = d + (2*i+2)
    sa += d
print(sa)
```

Использовав информацию [@S.H.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1338349), сделал такой код. Он намного быстрее моего старого.

---

PS если есть недочеты, буду непротив вашей критики.